# Geforce shadowplay screen recording, how do you zoom in to show something small?

Tags: nvidia-geforce-experience

Is this even possible to zoomin?

Answer (score 1):

This will have to be done afterwards in whatever editing program you use as Shadowplay just records (and now uploads to selected services) the gameplay.